# how is these two objects still equal after calling the toUpperCase function

Tags: java, string

What I read is that the function
`toUpperCase` actually returns a *new* String object, and I did check the code inside Java.lang.String and it really *creates* a new string.

this is a code from Java.lang.string class, method toUpperCase

```
        int resultOffset = 0;
        char[] result = new char[len]; /* may grow */
```

This is my code now:

```
    String s1 = new String("THAT");
    String s2 = s1;
    System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true
    s1 = s1.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(s1 == s2); // true, how is that?
```

The first (s1 == s2) returns true and that is obvious. But how can the second one returns true as well? after the toUpperCase method, shouldn't s1 becomes a new String? while s2 still points to the old s1. Thus, the memory location for both of them should be not the same, and as `==` compares the memory locations. the result should be false.

I know that I am wrong in some point of my argument, but where is that point?

Comment: _after the toUpperCase method, shouldn't s1 becomes a new String_ Why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because the toUpperCase method returns a new String, that is why i showed u the code from String class method toUpperCase

Comment: Why do you think it does?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think it creates a new object that references to a memory location which contains the upper value of that string `THAT`

Comment: Why do you think it returns a **new** instance instead of returning the **same** (the one it was invoked on) instance?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because I am having a course in Coursera java class, and that is what the teacher said, and then i checked the code and it actually creates a new String

Comment: @CrakC I know, but that is just the value, while `==` compare the reference, not the value

Comment: In this case, because the `String` is already in uppercase, it returns the `this`, the same `String`

Comment: here your question have answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: Obviously not, if your code is behaving this way.

Comment: @MadProgrammer that is an interesting idea, i though that in the beginning (the same case as substring), but then i read the code and in the code (you can check) they are creating a new char array regardless of checking if the string is already upper case

Comment: As stated in the linked post: _`toLowerCase()` would have recognized it, and returned the original string_. The same logic applies to `toUpperCase`, it returns the same string if there are no changes to be made. This is not explicitly stated, so don't depend on it.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I ran the `public String toUpperCase(Locale locale) {` method, they do a check to see if any of the characters need to be changed, if they don't it uses `return this` (line 2733 of the `String` class (Java 8)), otherwise it goes ahead and creates a new char array and generates a new `String`.  You could also print the `hashcode` of both `s1` and `s2`, in your above example, they are the same

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are right, now i see the `break scan` statement in the method. Then it is exactly the same situation as string . substring where the check if the beginning and the end are the same, they return the original string, otherwise, (after java 7) they return a new string, not a view of the old string.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis really duplicated? ?? ? ?? ? !!!! !!! !! do you really see that question talks about to upper case?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis oh yes it is duplicated sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the JDK `String.toUpperCase(Locale locale)` method body if the string is all Uppercase it returns the same String

```
        /* Now check if there are any characters that need to be changed. */
    scan: {
        for (firstLower = 0 ; firstLower < len; ) {
            int c = (int)value[firstLower];
            int srcCount;
            if ((c >= Character.MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE)
                    && (c <= Character.MAX_HIGH_SURROGATE)) {
                c = codePointAt(firstLower);
                srcCount = Character.charCount(c);
            } else {
                srcCount = 1;
            }
            int upperCaseChar = Character.toUpperCaseEx(c);
            if ((upperCaseChar == Character.ERROR)
                    || (c != upperCaseChar)) {
                break scan;
            }
            firstLower += srcCount;
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Oh god, i didn't see the `break scan` statement. That is the reason. Then if all the chars are already in the upper case mode, the code won't continue and the method will return **this**. (voted)

Answer (score 0):

Because `s1` is already uppercase. The JVM returns the same `intern`d `String`. You can explicitly make it a new one. Like,

```
String s1 = "THAT"; // <-- no need for new String here.
String s2 = new String(s1);
System.out.println(s1 == s2);
```

**or** change `s1` to lowercase first. Something like,

```
String s1 = "that";
String s2 = s1.toUpperCase();
System.out.println(s1 == s2);
```

In both cases, you'd get `false`.

Comment: This is another think, my question is why the result is true since the s1 and s2 reference now to different memory location. you gave me example about another issue